# Как правильно унаследоваться от встроеных функций-конструкторов через прототипы?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Большинство конструкторов кидают ошибку, что вызываются без new. Array ошибку не кидает, посколбку можно вызывать и без new:

```
'use strict';

const RevercedArray = function(...args) {
  Array.apply(this, args);
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(RevercedArray.prototype, Array.prototype);

const arr = new RevercedArray(1, 2, 3);

console.log(arr); // RevercedArray {}
```

Я хочу сделать что-то похожее на это:

```
const Rectangle = function(x, y, width, height) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
};

Rectangle.prototype.area = function() {
  return this.width * this.height;
};

const Square = function(x, y, length) {
  Rectangle.call(this, x, y, length, length);
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(Square.prototype, Rectangle.prototype);

const sq = new Square(1, 2, 3);
console.log(sq); // Square { x: 1, y: 2, width: 3, height: 3 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого вам пригодится метод [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct). Он как раз позволяет вызвать произвольную функцию так, как будто она была вызвана через new.

Таким образом, если вам очень важно унаследоваться от es6-класса через функцию и прототип, можно сделать примерно так:

```js
function MyClass(…) {
    if (new.target === undefined) throw …;
    var obj = Reflect.construct(MyParent, […], new.target);
    
    // …

    return obj;
}
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(MyParent.prototype);
```

Однако, в 2024м году можно бы уже и на классы перейти.